# Efficiently fill missing values in each column with different methods?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 |
|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|
|  1   | 10   | 1.3  | 0.193|
|  2   | 22   | 2.1  | 0.56 |
|  3   | 4    | -4   | nan  |
|  4   | nan  | nan  | nan  |
| nan  | 1    | 0    | 0.1  |
```

Is there an efficient way where I can fill the missing values in each column with a different method?

For example:

- 'num1' with forward fill
- 'num2' with backward fill
- 'num3' with interpolate
- 'num4' with mean of 'num4'

defined by a dictionary as:

`{'num1':'forward','num2':'backward','num3':'interpolate','num4':'mean'}`

Expected output:

```
| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 |
|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|
|  1   | 10   | 1.3  | 0.193|
|  2   | 22   | 2.1  | 0.56 |
|  3   | 4    | -4   | 0.284|
|  4   | 1    | -2   | 0.284|
|  4   | 1    | 0    | 0.1  |
```

Note: while the number of methods to use are finite, the number of columns can vary. The obvious way would be to loop through the dictionary, have some nested `if-elif`s and do it, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way

Thanks in advance!

*Edited to include more information

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy Included it now, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking @jezrael's solution a step further, and assuming this is what you have in mind, you can wrap it with `transform`:

```
df.transform(
    {
        "num1": lambda x: x.ffill(),
        "num2": lambda x: x.bfill(),
        "num3": lambda x: x.interpolate(),
        "num4": lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),
    }
)


    num1    num2    num3    num4
0   1.0     10.0    1.3     0.193000
1   2.0     22.0    2.1     0.560000
2   3.0     4.0     -4.0    0.284333
3   4.0     1.0     -2.0    0.284333
4   4.0     1.0     0.0     0.100000
```

You may try and use the getattr function to attempt this; like @jezrael said, you may have to test for speed, and possibly edge cases.

Also, the function below relies on you knowing the names of the built-in pandas functions (`ffill` is "ffill", ...)

Note that the code below still used `if/else` statements, since you are checking for various scenarios. I guess a safe bet would be to wrap the abstractions further into a function; hopefully this points you in the right direction::

```
# mapping with pandas function names 
mapping = {"num1": "ffill",
           "num2": "bfill", 
           "num3": "interpolate",
           "num4": "fillna"}


def func(df, key, value, *args, **kwargs):
    value = getattr(df.loc[:, key], value)(*args, **kwargs)
    return value

outcome = {
    key: func(df, key, value, df[key].mean())
    if value == "fillna"
    else func(df, key, value)
    for key, value in mapping.items()
}

df.assign(**outcome)
```

Again, test it and watch out for edge cases.

Comment: but if you don't know the number of columns before hand/number of columns is a lot, this wouldn't be ideal right?

Comment: i'm not sure I get your drift; if you dont know the column names, how will you fill them correctly?

Comment: maybe if you can share your thought process a bit better, then the answer can be modified appropriately, if possible.

Comment: Included more details in the question, I do hope I'm making more sense now

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with the format with which you constructed the 'outcome' dictionary, is it possible to have if-elif-else in that way too?

Comment: it is a dictionary comprehension; yes, you can have multiple if/elif/elses in there; too many and it could become incomprehensible

Answer (score 1):

You can processing each column/method separately:

```
df['num1'] = df['num1'].ffill()
df['num2'] = df['num2'].bfill()
df['num3'] = df['num3'].interpolate()
df['num4'] = df['num4'].fillna(df['num4'].mean())
```

If want specify multiple columns for some method pass them to lists:

```
d = {'num1':'forward','num2':'backward','num3':'interpolate','num4':'mean'}

for k, v in d.items():
    if v =='forward':
        df[k] = df[k].ffill()
    if v =='backward':
        df[k] = df[k].bfill()
    if v =='interpolate':
        df[k] = df[k].interpolate()
    if v =='mean':
        df[k] = df[k].fillna(df[k].mean())

print (df)
   num1  num2  num3      num4
0   1.0  10.0   1.3  0.193000
1   2.0  22.0   2.1  0.560000
2   3.0   4.0  -4.0  0.284333
3   4.0   1.0  -2.0  0.284333
4   4.0   1.0   0.0  0.100000
```

This should be used if want pass multiple lists, only necessary change format of dictionary to dict of lists:

```
d = {'num1':'forward','num2':'backward','num3':'mean','num4':'mean'}

from collections import defaultdict
d2 = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in d.items():
    d2[v].append(k)
    
print (d2)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'forward': ['num1'], 'backward': ['num2'],
                              'mean': ['num3', 'num4']})

for k,v in d2.items():
    if k =='forward':
        df[v] = df[v].ffill()
    if k =='backward':
        df[v] = df[v].bfill()
    if k =='interpolate':
        df[v] = df[v].interpolate()
    if k =='mean':
        df[v] = df[v].fillna(df[v].mean())

print (df)
   num1  num2  num3      num4
0   1.0  10.0  1.30  0.193000
1   2.0  22.0  2.10  0.560000
2   3.0   4.0 -4.00  0.284333
3   4.0   1.0 -0.15  0.284333
4   4.0   1.0  0.00  0.100000
```

Another idea is create dictionary of lambda functions:

```
d = {'num1':'forward','num2':'backward','num3':'interpolate','num4':'mean'}

d1 = {'forward': lambda x: x.ffill(),
      'backward': lambda x: x.bfill(),
      'interpolate': lambda x: x.interpolate(),
      'mean': lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())}

final = {k: d1[v] for k, v in d.items()}

df = df.transform(final)

print (df)
   num1  num2  num3      num4
0   1.0  10.0   1.3  0.193000
1   2.0  22.0   2.1  0.560000
2   3.0   4.0  -4.0  0.284333
3   4.0   1.0  -2.0  0.284333
4   4.0   1.0   0.0  0.100000
```

Comment: but if you don't know the number of columns before hand/number of columns is a lot, this wouldn't be ideal right?

Comment: @aswa09 - Do you think apply multiple columns for some method? Then use second solution with pass lists of columns names

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , I'm just wondering though, if we have a lot of data (100k+ rows & 100+ columns for instance) would this take too long?

Comment: @aswa09 - I think the best test in real data, I hope second solution should be fastest.